# Permission denied google beacon in Google Developer console

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibeacon, google-beacon-platform

I trying to accomplish request to Google Beacon API from Google Developer Console. And have an error.

```
{  "error": {
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
"message": "Unauthorized.", 
"code": 403  }}
```

I have OAuth data for my user.

Comment: The response you see is expected if you have not completed the OAuth process successfully before making the request.  It's impossible to say why this is happening without seeing more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare all the permission on Google Api console for Proximity Beacon Api in your service key configuration